# Win32::API perl Procedure not found

Tags: perl, winapi, activeperl

I am trying to use a Win32 dll from my perl code.

```
use Win32::API;
$Win32::API::DEBUG = 1;
$function = Win32::API->new(
  'mydll.dll', 'int myfunc()',
);
$return = $function->Call();
```

But I am getting following error:

```
Win32::API::new: Loading library 'mydll.dll'
(PM)parse_prototype: got PROC 'myfunc'
(PM)parse_prototype: got PARAMS ''
parse_prototype: IN=[  ]
parse_prototype: OUT='int' PACKING='i' API_TYPE=3
FAILED GetProcAddress for Proc 'myfunc': The specified procedure could not be found.
Can't call method "Call" on an undefined value at .\test_dll.pl line 6.
```

My dll is compiled with _cdecl calling convention. Does this make any difference?
I am using active perl 5.14 on windows 7

Comment: `mydll.dll` doesn't contain a function named `myfunc` with no arguments returning an `int`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you use `__declspec(dllexport)` to export functions from DLL? If yes, use `.def` file instead. Because `__declspec(dllexport)` will make the function name in export descriptor of DLL to have underscore precede; Or mangling function name if your function is C++.

The last time I used `Win32::API`, its does not support `__cdecl`. You should change it to `__stdcall` instead.

Comment: adding __declspec(dllexport) worked for me. The procedure reference is returned. I changed the calling since its _cdecl as
`$function = Win32::API->new(
  'mydll.dll', 'myfunc', 'I', undef, '_cdecl'
);

$return = $function->Call( );`

Although the script is crashing while calling the procedure.

Answer (score 0):

Use StudPE, PE Explorer, or dumpbin /exports to find out the real name of the function you want to use. This way you dont care if the function is name decorated or not. You know its real name.